# TypeError: string must be indices on JSON looping through feature array of objects in arcpy

Tags: python, json, arcpy

I am trying to loop through my json and only getting the feature array of objects and getting all the objects but I can't seem to understand where I doing wrong in my python code. Here is my code:

I have looked at these questions for advice but it doesn't seem to work. 
[TypeError: string indices must be integers error when parsing Json with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41836011/typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers-error-when-parsing-json-with-python)

```
jsonData = operationalLayers = None
#for testing purposes, parse from a json file
if Web_Map_as_JSON != '':
    jsonData = json.loads(Web_Map_as_JSON)
    operationalLayers = jsonData["operationalLayers"]
    arcpy.AddMessage("We have valid json data")
else:
    with open('json/WLA-FRI-AY-14-subset.json') as data:
        jsonData = json.load(data)
        operationalLayers = jsonData["operationalLayers"]
    print "We parsed json data from a file"

# looping thru only graphics-operation-layer and its sub layers
# and add attributes for each features on the layout
for ol in operationalLayers:
    #hard code the first feature layer
    if (ol["id"] == "ParcelRouteEditingTest_1259"):
        if (ol.has_key('featureCollection')):
            fcol = ol["featureCollection"]
            if (not fcol.has_key('layers')):
                continue
            lyrs = fcol["layers"]

            #loop through layer
            for i in lyrs:
                # feature set data on the graphic layer
                fs = i["featureSet"]
                # store attributes for easy access
                for featureData in fs:
                   featureDataObj = featureData[1]["features"]
                    print featureDataObj
                # queryURL = '{0}/query'.format(i['url'])
                # arcpy.AddMessage(queryURL)
                # getQuery = requests.get(queryURL)
                # if(getQuery.status_code == 200):
                #     fs = getQuery.json()
                    updateLayoutElementWithFeatureAttributes(feature_data_obj, None, pdfPaths)
```

Here is the structure of the json data:

[image: JSON structure]

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Workspace-TT\pythonprint\customPrint.py", line 299, in <module>
    featureDataObj = featureData[1]["features"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: `featureData[1]` is a list. You need another `for` loop to iterate over it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`featureSet` is not a list, it's a dictionary with `geometryType` and `features` as keys.

When you do

```
for featureData in fs:
```

you're iterating through those keys.

If what you mean is to iterate through the list under `features`, you should do something like

```
featureset['features'][i]
```

or

```
for feature in featureSet['features']
```

Comment: how would i iterate over all the keys if I want all the data under 1-5?

Comment: If you want specific indexes, use a for loop with range.
Ex. indexes 1 through 5 (so the second to the sixth elements):
for i in range(1, 6):
    feature = featureSet['features'][i]

Comment: the second one piece of code`for feature in featureSet['features']` returns the first one in the dictionary. what would help to make it iterate all the elements in the feature dictionary? Also, I dont know where to put the first one in my code.

Comment: Not sure what you mean..  that's a `for` loop and you need to iterate through the loop to access all members.  If it's iterating through a list, each iteration is over the elements of the list.  If it's iterating through a dictionary, each iteration is over the keys of the dictionary. Looks like you need to debug and step through the code to get a better understanding of what's going on..  If you use an IDE like PyCharm, this is super easy to do.